# How to get proxy info from client.Transport?

Tags: go

I need to make logs with a proxy, from which I send requests.
So, I have the following code:

```
proxy := fmt.Sprintf("%v", client.Transport)
log.Println("[GetRequest]Response status code &body response size.", proxy[19:69], response.StatusCode, len(body))
```

I know, that`s not correct, but how can I get only proxy.
If I will make code like this:

```
fmt.Println(reflect.ValueOf(client.Transport))
```

Then you will get a full answer.

```
&{{0 0} false map[{http://login:paroleM@ip:port https www.example.com:443 false}:[0xc000480120 0xc00034e5a0]
```

Comment: Are you asking how to get the transport's proxy function, or are you asking how to get the proxy used for a request?

Comment: @CeriseLimón "how to get the proxy used for a request", this one

Comment: I don't think there's a way to get the proxy used. You can get and call the transport's proxy function, but there's no guarantee that the proxy function returns the same URL for a given request.